# Editable JComboBox: Determining whether enter is pressed while ignoring it in drop down selection?

Tags: java, swing

I have a panel with a couple of text fields and an editable `JComboBox` used to perform a search. I want all of these to act as if I press the search button underneath when I press the enter key. This works fine for a `JTextField` with an `ActionListener`. However, I only want the `JComboBox` to start the search when enter is pressed and the drop down list isn't shown. I.e. if the user presses enter to select an option in the drop down nothing should happen.

How would I go about achieving this behaviour?

I tried checking `getActionCommand()` and it either shows `"comboBoxEdited"` or `"comboBoxChanged"` when the event is fired. `"comboBoxEdited"` is fired when enter is pressed after selecting an option as well as when pressing enter in the editable field. `"comboBoxChanged"` is fired when moving between options, as well as just before `"comboBoxEdited"` when enter is pressed after editing the text.

I tried an ugly hack where I store the previous `ActionCommand`, but it isn't perfect as the user will have to press enter twice after entering text manually.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("comboBoxEdited") &&
        !combohack.equals("comboBoxChanged")) {

        combohack="";
        //PERFORM SEARCH!
    }
    combohack=e.getActionCommand();
}
```

I furthermore tried to make my hack even uglier by adding a `KeyListener` as well to reset the string when actual letters where pressed, but that didn't help.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the difference between the user pressing [Enter] while editing the field and the user selecting an item from the drop down?

Comment: @MadProgrammer The user might want to enter something in other search fields by tabbing to these before the search should be carried out. It comes natural for most people to hit [Enter] when selecting an option with the arrow keys (although you could press [Tab]). The application isn't meant for using the mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this is a little heavy handed, but what this does is replaces the `KeyEvent.VK_ENTER` `Action` with our own `Action`

So basically, when the user presses the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, our `Action` is notified, but the combo box is not (so the `JComboBox` won't trigger an `ActionEvent` for it - but will for selection changes)

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.ComboBoxEditor;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            final JComboBox<String> cb = new JComboBox<>(new String[]{"Apples", "Bananas", "Pears"});
            cb.setEditable(true);
            SimpleComboBoxEditor editor = new SimpleComboBoxEditor();
            InputMap im = editor.getInputMap();
            ActionMap am = editor.getActionMap();
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0), "enter");
            am.put("enter", new AbstractAction() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (!cb.isPopupVisible()) {
                        System.out.println("Editor did action");
                    }
                    cb.hidePopup();
                }
            });
            cb.setEditor(editor);
            cb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Combobox did action");
                }
            });
            add(cb);
        }

        public class SimpleComboBoxEditor extends JTextField implements ComboBoxEditor {

            @Override
            public Component getEditorComponent() {
                return this;
            }

            @Override
            public void setItem(Object anObject) {
                if (anObject != null) {
                    setText(anObject.toString());
                } else {
                    setText(null);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem() {
                return getText();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

> Thanks for the effort! It doesn't really work as I want it to though. It still fires the event with "comboBoxEdited" when [Enter] is pressed to choose the highlighted item instead of just closing the drop down leaving the chosen text in the editor. It should only fire the event when the drop down is closed and the user presses [Enter]. So [Enter] to choose an item, [Enter] again to fire the action.

So, I finally got to run the code on a Windows machine and basically, in the `Action` for the key binding, I made a check for `isPopupVisible`, when it's not, it will print the "editor did action" event, otherwise it does nothing

Comment: Thanks for the effort! It doesn't really work as I want it to though. It still fires the event with `"comboBoxEdited"` when [Enter] is pressed to choose the highlighted item instead of just closing the drop down leaving the chosen text in the editor. It should only fire the event when the drop down is closed and the user presses [Enter]. So [Enter] to choose an item, [Enter] again to fire the action.

Comment: Then use the first approach and only react to the field itself

Comment: I'm using a Mac so I can't arrow through the options of the drop and press "enter" :P

Comment: Didn't know that wasn't possible on a Mac. Wouldn't it work if you didn't change the look & feel? Anyway I'm wondering whether it is possible somehow to detect if the drop down is shown. Then it might be possible to ignore [Enter].

Comment: You mean something like [`JComboBox#isPopupVisible`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#isPopupVisible--)?

Comment: Didn't know about that one. Thanks! It returns false when the `ActionEvent` is fired though. I'll play around with it tomorrow.

Comment: I've run it on a Windows box and update the code, the `AbstractAction` for the key binding now checks to see if the popup is displayed or not, when it's not, it prints the "editor action" message, otherwise it does nothing

Comment: Thanks. This works exactly as it should! I ended up not using the custom editor though and just cast the `EditorComponent` of the standard `JComboBox` to `JComponent` to get the `InputMap` and `ActionMap`: `((JComponent)combo.getEditor().getEditorComponent()).getInputMap()` etc.

Answer (score -1):

There is actually a rather simple and elegant solution:

```
combo.getEditor().getEditorComponent().addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER && !combo.isPopupVisible()) {
            System.out.println("SEARCH!");
        }
    }
});
```

Note that the `KeyListener` won't work if added to the `JComboBox` directly, but has to be added to its `EditorComponent`.

Comment: `KeyListener` is never the solution, especially when dealing with text components, there are just to many things that can wrong and to many better ways to solve the problem

Comment: @MadProgrammer Mind explaining what could go wrong or pointing me to some source?

Comment: As a general rule, key listener is a poor choice in almost all cases, you can't guarantee the order that events are delivered or if the key is consumed at some point in the event chain, when the field might have been updated, as a general rule of thumb, you should use key bindings, DocumentFilter or DocumentListener over KeyListener depending on what you are trying to achieve